# Is convergence in probability equivalent to convergence of all conditioned distributions?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I have a simple question regarding **potentially an alternative characterisation of convergence in probability**.

---

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space, and for each $E \in \mathcal{F}$ with $\mathbb{P}(E)>0$, define the probability measure $\mathbb{P}_E$ on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ by $\mathbb{P}_E(A)=\frac{\mathbb{P}(E \cap A)}{\mathbb{P}(E)}$.

Let $(S,d)$ be a separable metric space, and suppose we have a measurable function $X_n \colon \Omega \to S$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{\infty\}$.

> > Suppose that for every $E \in \mathcal{F}$ with $\mathbb{P}(E)>0$, $X_n \to X_\infty$ in distribution over $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P}_E)$ as $n \to \infty$. Does it follow that $X_n \to X_\infty$ in probability over $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ as $n \to \infty$?

[The converse direction is immediate from the fact that convergence in probability implies convergence in distribution, since convergence in probability over $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ clearly implies convergence in probability over $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P}_E)$.]

Comment: It is correct that my example was thinking over something else. However, I would suspect there is no implication. Would you mind explainin what makes you believe this implies convergence in probability? Recall that convergence in probability _signifies_ that every subsequence of $(X_n)$ has a itself a subsequence converging almost surely to $X_\infty.$ I just don't see how to extract the subsequence of the subsequence with convergence in distribution.

Comment: @WillM. Well, my intuition behind why it certainly seems feasible is something like as follows: Arguing by contrapositive, the failure of convergence in probability corresponds precisely to the existence of an $\varepsilon>0$ and a subsequence $(X_{m_n})$ such that $\mathbb{P}(d(X_{m_n},X_\infty)>\varepsilon)>\varepsilon$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. It seems strange for this to be compatible with the idea that for *every* positive-measure $E\in\mathcal{F}$ and every bounded continuous $g\colon S \to \mathbb{R}$, $\int_E g(X_{m_n})\,d\mathbb{P}\to\int_E g(X_\infty)\,d\mathbb{P}$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: I don't get how you can give a positive answer below. The classical example of a sequence that converges in distribution but not in probability is a sequence of iid random variables (provided the underlying space is not degenerate). But it also satisfies your assumption about the convergence in distribution of the conditional laws...

Comment: @Olivier No it does not satisfy my assumption about the convergence in distribution of the conditioned laws. Note that in my formulation, in the convergence of conditioned laws I'm fixing the event $E$ on which I'm conditioning, rather than letting it depend on $n$. What you're probably picturing is if I fixed a Borel set $A\subset S$ and then took the conditional distribution of $X_n$ conditioned on the event $E_n:=\{X_n\in A\}$.

Comment: you're right...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to work out now that the answer is *yes*.

Throughout the following, we assume as in the question that $(S,d)$ is a separable metric space.

**Definition.** For any Borel probability measure $\mu$ on $S$ and any $\varepsilon>0$, a **$(\mu,\varepsilon)$-partition of $S$** is a disjoint collection $\mathcal{P}$ of open sets $U \subset S$ such that $\mu(\bigcup_{U\in\mathcal{P}}U)=1$ and for each $U \in \mathcal{P}$, $\mathrm{diam}(U) \leq \varepsilon$ and $\mu(U)>0$.

**Lemma.** *For any Borel probability measure $\mu$ on $S$ and any $\varepsilon>0$, there exists a $(\mu,\varepsilon)$-partition of $S$.*

[The proof is based on what I think is a standard trick for constructing sets whose boundary has zero measure.]

*Proof of Lemma.* Let $(x_n)_{n\geq 1}$ be a dense sequence in $S$. For each $n$, since the uncountable family $\{\{x \in S : d(x,x_n)=r\}: r \in [\frac{\varepsilon}{3},\frac{\varepsilon}{2}]\}$ is mutually disjoint, there must exist $r_n \in [\frac{\varepsilon}{3},\frac{\varepsilon}{2}]$ such that $\mu(x \in S : d(x,x_n)=r_n)=0$. Now let $A_1=B_{r_1}(x_1)$ and for $n \geq 2$ let $A_n=B_{r_n}(x_n) \setminus \bigcup_{i=1}^{n-1} B_{r_i}(x_i)$. Note that $\{A_n:n \geq 1\}$ forms a partition of $S$ (in the purely set-theoretic sense). Since we have the general facts that $\partial(A \cup B) \subset (\partial A) \cup (\partial B)$ and $\partial(A \setminus B) \subset (\partial A) \cup (\partial B)$, it follows in particular that $\partial A_n$ is a $\mu$-null set for each $n$. So let $\mathcal{P}'=\{A_n^\circ: n \geq 1\}$ and let $\mathcal{P}$ be the set of all $\mu$-positive-measure members of $\mathcal{P}'$.

*Proof that the answer to the question is yes.* Fix $\varepsilon>0$; we need to show that $\mathbb{P}(d(X_n,X_\infty)\leq\varepsilon) \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$. Let $\mu$ be the distribution of $X_\infty$, and let $\mathcal{P}$ be a $(\mu,\varepsilon)$-partition of $S$. For each $U \in \mathcal{P}$, letting $E_U$ be the event $\{X_\infty \in U\}$, we obviously have that $\mathbb{P}_{E_U}(X_\infty \in U)=1$; and so since $U$ is open and $X_n$ converges in distribution to $X_\infty$ over $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P}_{E_U})$, it follows that $\mathbb{P}_{E_U}(X_n \in U) \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$. In other words,
$$ \mathbb{P}(X_n \in U \textrm{ and } X_\infty \in U ) \to \mathbb{P}(X_\infty \in U) \textrm{ as } n\to\infty $$
for each $U \in \mathcal{P}$. Therefore, by the discrete dominated convergence theorem we can sum over all $U \in \mathcal{P}$ to give
$$ \mathbb{P}(\exists \ U \in \mathcal{P} \textrm{ s.t. } X_n \in U \textrm{ and } X_\infty \in U ) \to 1 \textrm{ as } n\to\infty. $$
But for each $n$, we have that
$$ \{ \exists \ U \in \mathcal{P} \textrm{ s.t. } X_n \in U \textrm{ and } X_\infty \in U \} \subset \{d(X_n,X_\infty) \leq \varepsilon\}, $$
and so it follows that $\mathbb{P}(d(X_n,X_\infty)\leq\varepsilon) \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$ as required.